# Video Karaoke Development on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, video, sdk

I have a karaoke app that takes mp3+g files and mixes in the mic (using audio units)... and is able to record the final results to a raw pcm file.

I have potential clients asking me if I can do the same with a karaoke video file. So, can I...

1) playback a video and mix in the microphone audio?

2) take #1 and record it to a video file?

3) possibly even take the video camera and microphone inputs, and video audio... and save this to a file?

Thinking about this can I... take an mp3, camera and microphone inputs and mix all of these to a video file?

Thanks for any feedback!

- Brian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, all of these are possible. With the CD+G format, you will be a lot better off converting those to h.264 on the desktop and then loading them as movies with an AAC audio track. Attempting to write a CD+G parser for iOS would be a nightmare since so many CD+G files are badly broken. Also, CD+G files are shocking large, much larger than the MP3 files because CD+G is dumb uncompressed video from the 80's. It is a silly format.

Comment: CD+G is not a video format and they aren't shockingly large. they range on 2mbs per song. and if you are converting CD+G to video you are using the same "broken" files to make said video so there is no difference